# How to rewrite the following code without 'switch' and 'if-else' condition?

Tags: c++, if-statement, switch-statement

```
int main()
{
    switch (month) 
    {
    case 1:
        days = 31;
        break;
    case 2:
        days = 28;
        break;
    case 3:
        days = 31;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: and you thought that adding Java and C would help you?!

Comment: There are many ways to do this kind of mapping without using a `switch` of `if / else if` cascade.

Comment: Have you tried different solutions and failed? If so, please add them to your questions. Also, a reason for the desired reformat would be helpful.

Comment: Sounds like a job for simple lookup table: an array of `int`s, one for each month, each initialized to the number of days in the corresponding month.  Beware leap-years, however...

Comment: And what is the reason that you don't want to use `if` and `switch`? What do you expect from the alternative way to be better/different? Do you try to solve a problem you have with `if` and `switch`?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way of doing by having an array of `Day`s where the array indexing is corresponding to `month-1`.

[See a demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/J9Zyc3OxrUPeA1j7)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main() 
{
    using Day = int;
    const std::array<Day, 3> days{ 31 , 28, 31};

    const auto findDay = [&](const std::size_t month) /* noexcept -> const std::size_t*/  
    {
        if (1 <= month && month <= days.size()) return days[month - 1];
        std::cout << "Invalid month\n"; // if not found
        return 0;
    };

    std::cout << findDay(1) << '\n';
    std::cout << findDay(2) << '\n';
    std::cout << findDay(3) << '\n';
    std::cout << findDay(0) << '\n';
}
```

**Output**:

```
31
28
31
Invalid month
0
```

Comment: `std::map` for mapping a small set of sequential indices to other numbers is overkill

Comment: I am backing @StoryTeller. As simple array should be sufficient for this case. There's even no need for a `std::vector`. `std::array` or even a raw array would be fine.

Comment: The name of the lambda could have been a bit more meaning full: `findDaysInMonth` or something.